# Run statsd as a daemon on EC2 instances programatically

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, statsd, ebextensions

**EDIT:** *My goal is to be able to emit metrics from my spring-boot application and have them sent to a `Graphite` server. For that I am trying to set up `statsd`. If you can suggest a cleaner approach, that would be better.*

I have a Beanstalk application which requires `statsd` to run as a background process. I was able to specify commands and packages through `ebextensions` config file as follows:

```
packages:
  yum:
    git: []

commands:
  01_nodejs_install:
    command: sudo yum -y install nodejs npm --enablerepo=epel
    ignoreErrors: true

  02_mkdir_statsd:
    command: mkdir /home/ec2-user/statsd

  03_fetch_statsd:
    command: git clone https://github.com/etsy/statsd.git /home/ec2-user/statsd
    ignoreErrors: true

  04_run_statsd:
    command: node stats.js exampleConfig.js
    cwd: /home/ec2-user/statsd
```

When I try to deploy the application to a new environment, the EC2 node never comes up fully. I logged in to check what might be going on and noticed in `/var/log/cfn-init.log` that `01_nodejs_install`, `02_mkdir_statsd` and `03_fetch_statsd` were executed successfully. So I guess the system was stuck on the fourth command (`04_run_statsd`).

```
2016-05-24 01:25:09,769 [INFO] Yum installed [u'git']
2016-05-24 01:25:37,751 [INFO] Command 01_nodejs_install succeeded
2016-05-24 01:25:37,755 [INFO] Command 02_mkdir_statsd succeeded
2016-05-24 01:25:38,700 [INFO] Command 03_fetch_statsd succeeded
cfn-init.log (END)
```

I need help with the following:

- If there is a better way to install and run `statsd` while instantiating an environment, I would appreciate if you could provide details on that approach. This current scheme seems hacky.
- If this is the approach I need to stick with, how can I run the fourth command so that `statsd` can be run as a background process?

Answer (score 1):

Tried a few things and found that the following `ebextensions` configs work:

```
packages:
  yum:
    git: []

commands:
  01_nodejs_install:
    command: sudo yum -y install nodejs npm --enablerepo=epel
    ignoreErrors: true

  02_mkdir_statsd:
    command: mkdir /home/ec2-user/statsd

  03_fetch_statsd:
    command: git clone https://github.com/etsy/statsd.git /home/ec2-user/statsd
    ignoreErrors: true

  04_change_config:
    command: cat exampleConfig.js | sed 's/2003/<graphite server port>/g' | sed 's/graphite.example.com/my.graphite.server.hostname/g' > config.js
    cwd: /home/ec2-user/statsd

  05_run_statsd:
    command: setsid node stats.js config.js >/dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null &
    cwd: /home/ec2-user/statsd
```

Note that I added another command (`04_change_config`) so that I may configure my own `Graphite` server and port in `statsd` configs. This change is not needed to address the original question, though.

The actual `run` command uses `setsid` to run the command as a daemon.